# Agrupar datos por día con el formato de la fecha incluída en R

Tags: r

Tengo una serie de datos semihorarios (cada 30 min) y los estoy agrupando por día y desplegandolo en un dataSplit. El problema es que al momento de revisar no me incluye la hora y lo requiero. No se si deba insertar una columna extra en el groupDate.

```
      #AGRUPO POR FECHA
       groupData <- Data_complete %>%
       mutate(Fecha = as.Date(as.POSIXct(Fecha,format="%d/%m/%Y")))%>%
       group_by(Fecha)

      #SEPARO EN GRUPOS POR CADA DÍA
      dataSplit <- group_split(groupData)
```

El resultado es esto: Pero también necesito visualizar la hora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que formato tiene `Fecha`? ¿Puedes agregar algún ejemplo de esta variable?

Comment: El formato de la fecha es año-mes-dia hora:minuto:segundo 2015-05-13 08:30:00

Comment: ¿La hora esta en una columna separada de la fecha?

Comment: Tengo la fecha y la hora en la misma columna pero al agrupar los datos por día con el código establecido, no puedo mirar la hora.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás convirtiendo una `fecha/hora` en solo una `fecha` por lo que pierdes la parte horaria. Lo que puedes hacer es "truncar" la hora y mantener el tipo de dato, Ejemplo:

```
> as.POSIXct('21/07/2020 13:42:19',format="%d/%m/%Y %H")
[1] "2020-07-21 13:00:00 -03"
```

En tu caso, haría algo así:

```
Data_complete %>%
  mutate(FechaHora = as.POSIXct(Fecha,format="%d/%m/%Y %H"),
         Fecha = as.Date(as.POSIXct(Fecha, format="%d/%m/%Y"))) %>%
  group_by(Fecha) %>% 
  group_split() -> dataSplit
```

Como puedes ver, por un lado reconfiguramos el formato, para leer la hora y por el otro, dejamos de usar `as.Date()` para no perder la hora.

Comment: Funciona el código, el problema es que ya no se agrupa por día. Cómo se observaba en el dataSplit <- group_split(groupData) #SEPARO EN GRUPOS POR CADA DÍA

Comment: Pero entonces lo que necesitas hacer es hacer una columna para el "split" y otra para mantener la fecha con la hora

Comment: Si se podría decir que sí.

Comment: @Daniela, verifica entonces mi última edición